# How to get Wikipedia templates to work with MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, mediawiki-templates

I exported a category of Wikipedia, checking the include templates as I did so and imported it into a MediWiki install, but all the pages are messed up how do get all the necessary templates so the page displays properly?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to use [Special:Export](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aExport) and make sure the "Include templates" checkbox is checked. You will also very likely need the [ParserFunctions extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aParserFunctions) installed, and possibly [other extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aVersion#Installed_extensions). You may also need to copy supporting scripts or CSS rules from [MediaWiki:Common.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki%3aCommon.js), [MediaWiki:Common.css](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki%3aCommon.css), [MediaWiki:Vector.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki%3aVector.js), [MediaWiki:Vector.css](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki%3aVector.css), or the like.

If you've done the Special:Export thing and are still having problems, and have checked the documentation for the template for any specific notes on reuse, you could try asking on the template's talk page for help.